# Python и dll

Tags: python, c++

Можно ли воспользоваться dll написанной на C++ с использованием winapi в питоновском скрипте?

И если можно - то как?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python

Comment: А в линуксе и других юниксах можно подключать разделяемые библиотеки?

Comment: [вот тут что-то есть](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) 

    cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

Answer (score 1):

можно [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html), но не все.